# Sending data via sockets from c# to a node socket.io server

Tags: c#, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am currently trying to feed my socket.io server with data from my C# client. But I am not sure how to receive the message on the server.

My server code:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(9000);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
     console.log('Connected');
}
```

First of all I don't know which event I have to listen to, but nevertheless I am unable to send data to my server using the following client (which uses Websocket-sharp) code:

```
private void init()
        {
            // start socket connection
            using (var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=websocket"))
            {
                ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
                    API.consoleOutput("Message: " + e.Data);

                ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>
                    API.consoleOutput("Error: " + e.Message);

                ws.Connect();
                ws.Send("server");
            }
        }
```

The connection works, but how do I receive the message of the server? The sending does not fire an error, therefore I think it does work.

Comment: I think, your connection is not working, because `socket.io` doesn't uses `websocket` protocol exactly. So, `c#` `websocket` client can't communicate with `node.js` `socket.io` server. Probably, you can try https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet for `c#` `socket.io` client.

Comment: haven't found that one. Only an outdated one. Will try that later.

Comment: I ain't sure about the maintenance of `SocketIoClientDotNet`, but I can say for sure that `websocket-sharp` can't be directly used to communicate with `socket.io` server. https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/issues/81#issuecomment-104650660

Comment: `SocketIoClientDotNet` keeps reconnecting and does not fire the local `Socket.EVENT_CONNECT` event. Seems to be not working either.

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten this working for a UWP app that connects to a node.js server. Basically what I do is connect to a URL that looks like `ws://localhost:4200/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket`

the port number being something we chose.

once that is set I connect to the node.js socket io library via the following lines of code.

```
private async Task ConnectWebsocket() {
        websocket = new MessageWebSocket();
        Uri server = new Uri(WebSocketURI); //like ws://localhost:4300/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket

        websocket.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
        websocket.MessageReceived += Websocket_MessageReceived;
        websocket.Closed += Websocket_Closed;
        try {
            await websocket.ConnectAsync(server);
            isConnected = true;
            writer = new DataWriter(websocket.OutputStream);
        }
        catch ( Exception ex ) // For debugging
        {
            // Error happened during connect operation.
            websocket.Dispose();
            websocket = null;
            Debug.Log("[SocketIOComponent] " + ex.Message);

            if ( ex is COMException ) {
                Debug.Log("Send Event to User To tell them we are unable to connect to Pi");
            }
            return;
        }
    }
```

`

at this point your socket io on "connection" should fire on your server

then you can emit events to it like normal. except the C# socket code does *not* discriminate various channels so you must do so on your own. below is how we do it (aka SocketData and SocketIOEvent are classes we have defined)

```
private void Websocket_MessageReceived(MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args) {
        try {
            using ( DataReader reader = args.GetDataReader() ) {
                reader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;

                try {
                    string read = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                    //read = Regex.Unescape(read);
                    SocketData socc = SocketData.ParseFromString(read);
                    if (socc != null ) {
                        Debug.Log(socc.ToString());
                        SocketIOEvent e = new SocketIOEvent(socc.channel, new JSONObject( socc.jsonPayload));
                        lock ( eventQueueLock ) { eventQueue.Enqueue(e); }
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception ex ) {
                    Debug.Log(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex ) {
            Debug.Log(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

in our specific application we did not need to send messages to our server, so for that I do not have a good answer.